# How to do a special type of lookup join in R data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

How to do a special type of lookup join in R data.table ?

Suppose there are two tables in R as under:

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(a = c("p", "q", "r"),
                  b = c("1,2", "1,2,3", "4,5"))

dt2 <- data.table(code = 1:5,
                  desc = c("good", "better", "best", "bad", "worst"))
```

They look like:

```
> dt1
   a     b
1: p   1,2
2: q 1,2,3
3: r   4,5
```

```
> dt2
   code   desc
1:    1   good
2:    2 better
3:    3   best
4:    4    bad
5:    5  worst
```

The goal is join `dt1` and `dt2` in such a way the `result` looks like

```
> result
   a     b             desc
1: p   1,2      good,better
2: q 1,2,3 good,better,best
3: r   4,5        bad,worst
```

Can anyone show how this type of join can be accomplished in R ?

Comment: @chinsoon12 Thanks for working code. Can you kindly post `match` code for non-sorted `dt2$code` column as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not really a join but as `dt1$b` contains convoluted values anyway here is my ugly hack:

```
dt2[, code := as.character(code)] 
dt1[, desc := b]
for (i in seq_along(dt2$code)) 
  dt1[, desc := stringr::str_replace_all(desc, dt2$code[i], dt2$desc[i])]
dt1[]
```

> ```
>    a     b             desc
> 1: p   1,2      good,better
> 2: q 1,2,3 good,better,best
> 3: r   4,5        bad,worst
> ```

#### Edit:

The replacement has to be done from the longest to the shortest `code` (string lengths or number of characters) and `desc`  *must not contain any digits*.

So, with `setorder(dt2, -code)` added to the code and the new use case provided by the OP [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8079808/san):

```
dt1 <- data.table(a = c("p", "q", "r"), b = c("1,21", "23,11,36", "11,36"))
dt2 <- data.table(code = c(1,11,21,23,36), desc = c("good", "better", "best", "bad", "worst"))

setorder(dt2, -code) # set order first (descending numeric value)
dt2[, code := as.character(code)] # then convert to character
dt1[, desc := b]
for (i in seq_along(dt2$code)) 
  dt1[, desc := stringr::str_replace_all(desc, dt2$code[i], dt2$desc[i])]

dt1[]
```

> ```
>    a        b             desc
> 1: p     1,21        good,best
> 2: q 23,11,36 bad,better,worst
> 3: r    11,36     better,worst
> ```

#### Edit 2:

According to [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68542118/how-to-do-a-special-type-of-lookup-join-in-r-data-table/68543143?noredirect=1#comment121145275_68543143) the requirement for the ugly hack *no digits in `desc`* aren't fulfilled in the production data. (As it almost always happens when a quick & dirty solution meets real world's data :-) ).

So here is a concise `data.table` solution which does what all the others answers do as well: split column `b`, join or look up the matching `desc`, and recombine:

```
dt2[, code := as.character(code)][
  dt1[, strsplit(b, ","), by = .(a, b)], on = "code==V1"][
    , .(desc = paste(desc, collapse = ",")), by = .(a, b)]
```

Using OP's new use case

> ```
>    a        b             desc
> 1: p     1,21        good,best
> 2: q 23,11,36 bad,better,worst
> 3: r    11,36     better,worst
> ```

Note that grouping uses both columns `a` and `b` for two reasons:  1) convenience (to keep both columns in the final result), 2) in case `a` is *not* a unique identifier

Comment: Works ok for single digit dt2$code values. If dt2$code has value 14 (not present in this example), then the new column will have replacement values of 1 and 4 concatenated.

Comment: I understand. Then dt2 has to be ordered so that the longest codes are replaced first. Will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: eg, does not work for `dt1 <- data.table(a = c("p", "q", "r"), b = c("1,21", "23,11,36", "11,36"))` and `dt2 <- data.table(code = c(1,11,21,23,36), desc = c("good", "better", "best", "bad", "worst"))`. Gives output:    `a                  b
1: p         good,2good
2: q bad,goodgood,worst
3: r     goodgood,worst`

Comment: Unfortunately, the condition that the `desc` column must not contain digits does not work for my actual large data set. Some of the actual values in `desc` column are like "Marks less than 50%". Then the value 5 (part of 50%) gets replaced by the 5th value.

Comment: Well, OK, I see _quick & dirty hack meets the real world_ :-( I have edited my answer again.

Comment: Solution in `Edit 2` works perfectly fine for my actual dataset. And the result exports perfectly fine as an Excel file too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Idea is to get column `b` as list of  integers and then subset column `desc` in `dt2` (note that `code` is just row number, otherwise use function `match`).

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

dt1[, b := map(b, ~str_split(.x, ",") %>% unlist() %>% as.integer())]
dt1[, desc := map(b, ~dt2$desc[match(.x, dt2$code)])]
```

Comment: Seems to work ok if dt$code values are strictly sequential. If there is a final value after a long gap in sequence, it is not able to replace that value. Can you please post `match` function solution.

Comment: Sure, I've adapted it

Comment: This code works for my actual large data set. But when exporting result to Excel file with `writexl::write_xlsx()` function, the second and third columns turn out to be blank. Using `fwrite` to export to csv and then using Excel or LibreOffice to convert to xlsx works, but is there a way to export it to Excel format directly?

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

dt1 <- data.table(a = c("p", "q", "r"),
                  b = c("1,2", "1,2,3", "4,5"))

dt2 <- data.table(code = 1:5,
                  desc = c("good", "better", "best", "bad", "worst"))

dt1 <- dt1[, list(b = unlist(strsplit(x = b, split = ","))), by = "a"] %>% 
  .[, b := type.convert(b)]

dt2[dt1, on = c("code == b")] %>% 
  .[, lapply(.SD, toString), by = "a"]
#>    a    code               desc
#> 1: p    1, 2       good, better
#> 2: q 1, 2, 3 good, better, best
#> 3: r    4, 5         bad, worst
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: In the actual dataset, values in `dt1$a` are not necessarily unique, hence grouping by `dt1$a` will cause reduction of the no. of rows of original table, which is not desirable. For example, it won't work for `dt1 <- data.table(a = c("p", "q", "r", "q"), b = c("1,21", "23,11,21", "11,36", "21,36"))` and `dt2 <- data.table(code = c(1,11,23,21,36), desc = c("good", "better", "best", "bad", "worst"))`

Answer (score -1):

You can split the string on comma and do a join.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt1 %>%
  separate_rows(b, sep = ',\\s*', convert = TRUE) %>%
  left_join(dt2, by = c('b' = 'code')) %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarise(desc = toString(desc))

#   a     desc              
#  <chr> <chr>             
#1 p     good, better      
#2 q     good, better, best
#3 r     bad, worst
```

Comment: In the actual dataset, values in `dt1$a` are not necessarily unique, hence `group_by` and `summarize` will cause reduction of the no. of rows of original table, which is not desirable. For example, it won't work for `dt1 <- data.table(a = c("p", "q", "r", "q"), b = c("1,21", "23,11,21", "11,36", "21,36"))` and `dt2 <- data.table(code = c(1,11,23,21,36), desc = c("good", "better", "best", "bad", "worst"))`